# Calculating degrees between 2 points with inverse Y axis

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, degrees

I'm creating a simple 2D game in javascript/canvas.
I need to figure out the angle of a certain object relative to my position.

So: say I'm at (10,10) and the object is at (10,5) - that would result in 90 degrees (as positive Y is down, negative Y is up)
(10,10) vs (10,15) would be 270 degrees.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Angle viewed from where?

Comment: I'm confused as to how you're determining the angle...are you facing in a certain direction the entire time?

Comment: @rownage: Unless I've misunderstood, the point is to determine the orientation of the vector that points from one position to the other.

Comment: @Tim: Yeah I was lost there, I understood what was going on after seeing KennyTM's answer (nothing like a good answer to help make sense of a question)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Suppose you're at (a, b) and the object is at (c, d). Then the relative position of the object to you is (x, y) = (c - a, d - b).

Then you could use the [`Math.atan2()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Math/atan2) to get the angle in radians.

```
var theta = Math.atan2(-y, x);
```

note that the result is in the range [-π, π]. If you need nonnegative numbers, you have to add

```
if (theta < 0)
   theta += 2 * Math.PI;
```

and convert radians to degrees, multiply by `180 / Math.PI`.

Answer (score 6):

If your coordinates are (xMe, yMe) and their coordinates are (xThem, yThem), then you can use the formula:

`arctan((yMe-yThem)/(xThem-xMe))`

Normally it'd be `arctan((yThem-yMe)/(xThem-xMe))`, but in this case the sign of the y-axis is reversed.

To convert the result from radians to degrees multiply by 180/pi.

So in JavaScript, this would look like: `Math.atan((yThem-yMe)/(xThem-xMe))*180/Math.PI`

atan gives a value between -pi/2 and pi/2 (that is, between -90 and 90 degrees). But you can look at what quadrant your (xThem - xMe, yMe - yThem) vector is in and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I actually like KennyTM's answer better. Math.atan2 will know which quadrant you're in already, so you're spared the last step.

Comment: I still found this answer useful, it's a nice alternative because I want to control the quadrants my self.

Comment: pi/2 is 180 degrees, not 90

Comment: @JasonBoyd You're mistaken. pi radians =180 degrees. A full circle is 2pi radians.

Comment: Ah right. Man when I get code head I get fuzzy on the maths.

Answer (score 4):

In layman's terms:

```
function pointDirection(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 canvas the origin is the top left corner hence the y axis grows from top to bottom. So regardless of wherever you are on the unit circle to calculate the angle of point A to the center(C) you should in fact do like

`angle = Math.atan2(Cy-Ay,Ax-Cx)`

and you will get your result in the range of [-π, π].

I have no idea why they haven't made the canvas origin the bottom left corner.